# Cannot Develop Office 2010 Addin Using VS2013 or VS2015 with Office 365 Installed

Tags: vsto

I have Office 2010 installed (and Office 365 as it happens), and am trying to develop an Outlook 2010 Add-in using VS2013 and VB.

I create a new Outlook 2010 Add In. Compile and Run the default app ("ThisAddIn"). Outlook 2010 opens OK. So far so good. Exit Outlook 2010.

Save the OutlookAddIn project.

Close VS2013

Restart VS2013. Try to open the saved project/ .sln and then get a "One Way upgrade" splash screen. Why...????

Tried the "upgrade", and it fails. "One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly...etc etc"

Output windows shows: "   The application for the project is not installed" (That seems to indicate the solution "thinks" it's looking for an Office version other than Office 2010, I believe)

Solution Explorer window shows "OutlookAddIn1(loading)...The project file will load in the background" and the "One-way upgrade" splash returns.

Cancel that.

Solution Explorer window now shows "OutlookAddIn1(**needs migration**)...The project file will load in the background".

I try "Reload Project" in solution explorer. It appears to do so.

I try to run the app again, I get a dialog saying " You cannot debug or run this project, because the required version of Microsoft Office application is not installed".

Check Project Properties and ALL references appear to have gone. (?????)

I've reinstalled VS2010 Tools. That didn't work either.

I have tried VS2015 and get exactly the same behavior.

So....... I uninstalled Office 365 completely. That didn't work either.

Any clues please?

Comment: Can you post your project file (i.e. the XML contained in the OutlookAddIn1.csproj or OutlookAddIn1.vbproj file)?

Comment: OutlookAddin1.vbproj. OK. I'm trying to find out how to post that. Not intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, but don't know for sure what caused it. I suspect there were some corrupted pointers in Windows that were "confusing" Outlook 2016 with Outlook 2010. The only clues I had to this were that in the Control Panel>Default Items>Set Your Default Programs, the default app for mail was shown as Outlook 2016, but its associated description was all about Outlook 2010.

So I did a complete uninstall of Office 365 (Office 2016) followed by a complete uninstall of Office 2010. I then cleaned out as many registry entries and folders associated with those as I could.

I then reinstalled Office 365, followed by Office 2010. Now I can develop an Outlook 2010 app in VS2013 or 2015 as normal. So the problem is apparently solved without knowing its cause.